# Creating event triggers dynamically with Unity 4.6 UI tools

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm having a bit of trouble with Unity 4.6's new UI tools.

On the canvas I have a list of toggles that are created dynamically at runtime (I'm following the instructions of this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRLsmuYMs8Q more or less). I'm trying to add a trigger to every one of the toggles, that would call a function *ListManager.LoadModel(int)*, when the toggle is clicked. Every toggle's event would have a different int assigned to it (the first one would call *LoadModel(0)*, the second *LoadModel(1)* and so on).

It's easy to create a list of toggles manually and hardcode the calls to every one of them in Inspector but I cannot figure out how add the triggers to the toggles as I'm creating them dynamically with the script. Any suggestions?